# Displaying a messge when search not found

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have done a filtering method using Django. The filtering is based on a choice selected from a drop down menu and a text input. the filtering is working fine. Now i want to display a message if the search is not found. Can somebody help me to solve this. Will post my code here.

```
def filter(request):
    val3='' 
    if request.GET.has_key('choices'):
        val2=request.GET.get('choices')
    if request.GET.has_key('textField'):
        val3=request.GET.get('textField')
    if request.POST:
        val2=request.POST.get('choices')    
        val3=request.POST.get('textField')
    if val2=='Designation':                
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation=val3) 
        flag=True 
    elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName__icontains=val3)
        flag=True 
    elif val2=='EmployeeID':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(employeeID=val3)  
        flag=True       
    elif val2=='Project':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(project=val3)   
        flag=True   
    elif val2=='DateOfJoin':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(dateOfJoin=val3) 
        flag=True       
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList/')
```

**html**

```
<h4 align="left">
{%for data in newData%}
<a STYLE="text-decoration:none" href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{data.id}}?choices={{val2}}&textField={{val3}}&flag=1 ">
{{ data.userName}}<br>
{%endfor%} 
</h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check newdata in filter view or in html ... if its empty show your msg

example :

```
{% if newData %}
    newData
{% else %}
    error
{% endif %}
```

- anything is anything you want check is empty?

Comment: given like that gives me this error..     TemplateSyntaxError at /filter/
Unused 'is' at end of if expression.

Answer (score 1):

How about display a message if the flag was not set to true or if newData is null when you can't find anything?

```
{% if flag is None or flag == False or newData is None %}
    <span>Error Message</span>
{% endif %}
```

You might want to check to see if it's necessary to check for flag is null too... can't tell from your posted code if that is necessary.

HTH

Comment: i got this error trying to do this way.  TemplateSyntaxError at /filter/

Could not parse the remainder: '!flag' from '!flag'

Answer (score 1):

If you're a little bit 'clever' with how you name your get/post variables, you can minimize your view code significantly.

```
def filter(request):
    fieldname = request.GET.get('choices', None) or request.POST.get('choices')
    value = request.GET.get('textField', None) or request.POST.get('textField')

    if fieldname is None or value is None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList/')

    new_data = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(**{fieldname:value})
    # use new_data for your purposes here, without the flag
```

However, you need to make sure that the GET or POST variable names in choices exactly match (including case) the field names of your model.

Then in your template:

```
<h4 align="left">
{%for data in new_data %}
    <a STYLE="text-decoration:none" href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{data.id}}?choices={{val2}}&textField=   {{val3}}&flag=1 ">
    {{ data.userName}}<br>
{%endfor%}
{% if new_data is None %}
    <div class='error'> No Data </div>
{% endif %}
</h4>
```